# Употребление глаголов совершенного или несовершенного вида после - "хочу"

Tags: грамматика

Я хочу *кушать* или *покушать*?
Я хочу *говорить* *или сказать*?

Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

Я хочу есть. Или (ребенку): ты хочешь кушать?

Я хочу сказать (сообщить определенную информацию).

Общего правила нет: глагол хотеть может сочетаться с глаголами любого вида, потому задача решается для каждого конкретного случая:

я хочу рисовать, играть (чем-то заниматься);

я хочу уехать, выспаться, измениться, стать писателем.

Comment: Но есть вообще какая то правила? Когда мне надо использовать свр или нвр вид после глагола ХОТЕТЬ?

Comment: Нет правил. Vera пишет так, как будто "хочу поесть" или "хочу говорить" - неверно, но это не так.  Можно сказать "хочу спать" или "хотят наслаждаться" (несовершенные глаголы).

Comment: Пример: "Джо догадался, что сегодня я хочу говорить о них".  То есть не просто говорить, а  говорить что, как, о чём. И другой пример: Кто хочет сказать? - Я хочу сказать. (Вот о чем была речь).

Comment: тогда когда информация определенная мне надо использовать нвр вид. 
На пример;
Я хочу пиццу есть
я хочу сесть
Я хочу говорить о проблемах нашей школы 
я хочу сказать 

Так правильно?

Comment: @AngelAlmera : "нвр"?  Попробуйте без txtspk, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Vera : Наличие дополнения ("говорить о чём-то") не делает глагол ("говорить") совершённым.

Comment: Дело не в том, какой вид у глагола, а в том, что  глагол "говорить" имеет незаполненную валентность, в отличие от глагола "сказать".

Comment: И как это относится к теме вопроса?  Мне понять хочется...